# I am writing code for a card game. In my deal cards function the program gets stuck and I can't determine why

Tags: c, linked-list

The program is getting stuck in the deal function, it does not print the next statement in main after being called. The deal function is supposed to alternate between players, dealing 5 cards to each using the linked list next. Each card has a face and a suit.

```
typedef struct card_s {
    char suit[20];
    int face;
    struct card_s *next;
}card;

void Dealcards(card** deck,card** p1,card** p2,card** Tail,card** Tail2 ) {

    int i;

    card* temp = NULL;
    card* prev = NULL;
    card* current = NULL;
    card* temp2 = NULL;
    card* prev2 = NULL;

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i += 1) {   

        current = *deck;

        if (i % 2 == 0) {   //alternate who card is deal to

            temp = (card*)malloc(sizeof(card));
            temp->face = current->face;     //give p1 card value
            strcpy(temp->face, current->face);      //give p1 card suit
            temp->next = NULL;

            if (prev == NULL){

                *p1 = temp;

            }
            else {

                prev->next = temp;      //next card
            }
        prev = temp;
        prev->next = NULL;

        }
        else {  //cpu dealt hand

            temp2 = (card*)malloc(sizeof(card));
            temp->face = current->face;     //give p2 card value
            strcpy(temp2->face, current->face);     //give p2 card suit
            temp2->next = NULL;

            if (prev2 == NULL) {

                *p2 = temp2;

            }
            else {
                prev2->next = temp2;    //next card
            }
            prev2 = temp2;
            prev->next == NULL;
        }
    }
    *Tail = prev;
    *Tail2 = prev2;
    return;
}

int main() {

    char YorN = 'Y';

    int playerCoins=100;
    int p1handlength;

    card *cards = NULL;
    card *player1 = NULL;
    card *player2 = NULL;
    card *Tail1 = NULL;
    card *Tail2 = NULL;

    while (YorN == 'Y') {

        printf("********Now playing Jacks Or Better********\n");

        makeDeck(&cards);   //create deck

        int decklength = findLength(cards); //gets length of deck used in shuffle function

        //shuffleDeck(&cards,decklength);   //shuffle deck

        printf("Dealing cards...\n\n");
        Dealcards(&cards, &player1, &player2, &Tail1, &Tail2);  //deal cards to cpu and player 2 (cpu)

        printf("P1 firstcard:\n");
        printf("Player 1's cards:\n");
        p1handlength = findLength(player1);
        PrintHand(player1,p1handlength);


    }

    return 0;
}
```

The function should deal 5 cards to each hand p1, and p2. I can't figure out what it is currently doing and whats getting stuck.

Comment: Please read: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: In `strcpy(temp->face, current->face); //give p1 card suit` should that be `strcpy(temp->suit, current->suit);` since `temp->face` is `int` and anyway you wrote to it only on the line above. ? Please take notice of compiler warnings.

Comment: Ok, I don't know how I didnt catch that but it helped a bunch, now the code gets through the deal function and prints player ones hand. However, the players hand is all the same card so I don't think the funtion is incrementing current. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

this:

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i += 1) {   

    current = *deck;
```

Should be:

```
current = *deck;
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++, current++) {
```